# Get Array of Input fields values and append itinto the associated textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some input field dynamically generated inside form. I am trying to read the value of hidden input and append to to the end of text area

```
   .<input type="hidden" id="formtype_loans_0_comment" name="formtype[loans][0][comment]" disabled="disabled" value="VAlue 1 value 123" />
    <textarea id="formtype_loans_0_description" name="formtype[loans][0][description]">Text Area 1 or 1 </textarea>

    <input type="hidden" id="formtype_loans_1_comment" name="formtype[loans][1][comment]" disabled="disabled" value="VAlue value 123" />
    <textarea id="formtype_loans_1_description" name="formtype[loans][1][description]">test desc</textarea>
```

and Here is the js  code, but it's not working,

```
var values = [];

$("input[name='formtype[loans][][description]']").each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
alert(values);
```

Comment: Your selector doesn't match the name of the elements: you can't use `[]` and expect it to match `[0]` and `[1]`. And your selector seems to be trying to match the names of the textareas, not the names of the input elements. As an aside, why would you have `disabled` set on hidden inputs?

Comment: it's been generated dynamically to 14 to 15 times, how would i know [0] [1] .. .. and so on.

Comment: Your question title mentioned an array, but your actual HTML seems to have one input per textarea. Is the idea to just copy the text from the input to its associated textarea?

Comment: Yes, i want to copy the each hidden input value to associated text area.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `"input[name='formtype[loans][][description]']"` won't match any elements, because the `[]` in the middle will not match to the `[0]` or `[1]` (etc.) in the middle of the actual element `name` attributes.

For the HTML shown you could use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `[name^=value]`:

```
$('input[name^="formtype[loans]"]').each(function() {
```

If each textarea will always immediately follow its associated hidden input then within the `.each()` loop that iterates over the inputs you can say `$(this).next()` to get the textarea.

If the textareas might be elsewhere in the DOM then you could find them by selecting by the `name` attribute based on the name of the current input:

```
$('textarea[name="' + this.name.replace("comment", "description") + '"')
```

Demonstrated in context:

```js
$('input[name^="formtype[loans]"]').each(function() {
  var val = this.value
  // add input's value to end of associated textarea's existing value:
  $('textarea[name="' + this.name.replace("comment", "description") + '"')
    .val(function(i, v) { return v + ' ' + val })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="formtype_loans_0_comment" name="formtype[loans][0][comment]" disabled="disabled" value="Hidden value 0" />
<textarea id="formtype_loans_0_description" name="formtype[loans][0][description]">Text Area A</textarea>

<input type="hidden" id="formtype_loans_1_comment" name="formtype[loans][1][comment]" disabled="disabled" value="Hidden value 1" />
<textarea id="formtype_loans_1_description" name="formtype[loans][1][description]">Text Area B</textarea>
```

If you want to simply replace the textarea's current value rather than adding to the end of it then you can simplify the above to:

```
$('input[name^="formtype[loans]"]').each(function() {
  $('textarea[name="' + this.name.replace("comment", "description") + '"')
    .val(this.value)
})
```

Comment: Without jQuery, it won't. With jQuery it does.

Comment: You can see that it works because my demo can be run directly from this page. As David indicated, you need to add jQuery to your fiddle.

Comment: One issue i see, there are other elements on the page too that also starts with `formtype[loans]` too like `formtype[loans][1][name]`.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to give the elements a common class and select by that instead of the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = [],
    inputs = $('input[type="hidden"]'),
    textareas = $('textarea');

if (inputs.length === textareas.length) {
    $.each(inputs, function(i, input) {
        var val = ($(input).val()) ? $(input).val(): undefined;
        if (val) {
            $(textareas).eq(i).empty().val(val);
        }
    });
}

alert(values);
```

The working code above assumes a couple of things:

1. There will always be one textarea per hidden input.
2. The associated textarea will always be the next sibling after the hidden input.

Even if that is not the case, there are still various ways to resolve this challenge. But I'll break down the different parts of the code:

First, instantiate your variables. Most importantly, cache your selected HTML elements into vars: touching the DOM is *expensive* and negatively impacts performance (e.g. querying the DOM each time in a loop).

Next, we put a conditional test to ensure there is one textarea for each input. No need to waste time iterating through a loop looking for elements that aren't there.

Finally, iterate through each of the selected inputs confirming each of them have a value. Again, no need manipulating textarea if there is no value to insert. If there is a value in the input, insert it into the textarea that occupies the same position as the input in each of your arrays of elements.